# I'm getting an errors after upgrade the Magento

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

**Hi, I am new to this Magento development I upgraded to version 2.3 to 2.4 after upgrading I got these errors can you please help me how to fix these errors?**

ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist in /home/vydw/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:24

Stack trace: #0 /home/vydw/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(24): ReflectionClass->__construct()

#1 /home/vydw/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(54):
Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor()

#2 /home/vydw/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters()

#3 /home/vydw/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()

#4 /home/vydw/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(237): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create()

#5 /home/vydw/public_html/pub/index.php(28): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication() #6 {main}

**I got some suggestions in the internet to compile the project so I run this code in the terminal bin/magento setup:di:compile but this also I got this error.**

this is my url http://vyd.w3in1web.com/

[image]

Comment: The error when you compile the code indicates that the WeltPixel Layered Navigation extension in your project is not compatible with the new Magento version. I thought you might be using an outdated version of the WeltPixel Layered Navigation extension. Try updating it to the latest version and run the bin/magento setup:upgrade and compile the code again.

Comment: I can't access the magento cms then how I can upgrade the wetpixel?

Comment: You must have access to the server to perform this upgrade. So... how you upgrade Magento from the older version?

Comment: Wetpixel 2.3 
1st disable the modules in cms after that replace the theme files and access the pearl them installation file through the url and do the changes and the clear cache through the cms

Comment: You've misunderstood my point. I meant that you need to upgrade (update) the extension via SSH. Here is the guide to assist you: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/modules/upgrade.html?lang=en. When upgrade Magento 2.3 to 2.4, you will need to upgrade third-party extensions and your custom modules to compatible with Magento 2.4.

Comment: this is weltpixel peral theme file how I can upgrade this using ssh

Comment: So..there are a lot of work when upgrading from Magento 2.3 to 2.4. To upgrade Weltpixel pearl theme you can search and follow their document. https://support.weltpixel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004480528-How-can-I-upgrade-update-the-Pearl-Theme-to-the-latest-version